# Rails pagination of subset of a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app and I'm trying to set up pagination for a view of the Essays class. I'm new to rails... so I can do this for ALL of them, but I only want certain ones to be in this list (where all the essays are contained in `Essay.find(Ranking.where(:user_id=>current_user.id).essay_id)`).

home.html.erb contains (among other things):

```
`<%= will_paginate @essays%>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @essays %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate @essays%>`
```

in the Pages Controller:

```
def home
     #...
      @essays = Essay.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

I tried adding `@essays=Essay.find(Ranking.where(:user_id=>current_user.id).essay_id)` before the `@essays=Essay.paginate(:page => params[:page])` but the method `essay_id` for the Ranking class is not available here. How do I get around this? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested this but try `current_user.rankings.collect{|ranking| ranking.essay}.paginate...`

Comment: @sscirrus, wouldn't this paginate rankings instead of essays?

Comment: @mischa - you're right, I apologize for the error. I'm up a little late tonight! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Essay.joins(:rankings)
  .where(:rankings => {:user_id => current_user.id})
  .paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Comment: I put `where` and `paginate` on new lines to make it more readable. Obviously you can just write it as one long line.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. Since I'm just starting with rails I'll have to look at the API for the joins method.

Comment: Your're welcome. If you are just starting with Rails, I recommend you have a look at Rails Guides. The basics are explained very clearly and it's also much better readable than an API: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon. This doesn't quite work and I have no idea how to get any of this to work. I want all essays that have an ID which the current_user has not (I left out the not before) ranked. Rankings has a user_id and an essay_id to tell which user and essay it corresponds to. I have no idea how to even display this, let alone paginate it.... : /

Answer (score 0):

While this can be done with will_paginate. I've had some issues with this plugin for Rails 3. A much smoother solution, in my opinion, was to use another pagination plugin called [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).

Assuming, essay_id is passed as a param, you could try:

```
@ranking = Ranking.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :essay_id => params[:essay_id]).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Or depending on your logic. If the essay object has already been identified in your controller:

```
@essay = Essay.find(1234)
@ranking = Ranking.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :essay_id => @essay.id).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

And then, in your view:

```
<%= paginate @ranking %>
```

Even better, to get you started on Kaminari, you can view this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari). As noted from the rails cast:

> The first-choice gem for pagination in
>   Rails is will_paginate, but the
>   currently released version doesn’t
>   support Rails 3. There is a
>   pre-release version available that
>   works but it hasn’t been updated for
>   several months. If will_paginate is no
>   longer in active development are there
>   any other gems we could use?
>
> One alternative is Kaminari. This
>   seems to provide a cleaner
>   implementation of pagination and
>   offers several improved features, too,
>   so let’s try it in our application
>   instead.

Hope that helps!

Comment: What problems do you find with will_paginate? I'll try this out another time if not for this page. Thanks for the input.

Comment: It was sometime ago since I made the decision to switch. I can't remember exactly what problem I encountered. Possibly something with scopes. It seems Kaminari is keeping things up to date, which is enough reason to stick with it

Answer (score -1):

Simply chain `paginate` method after `find` method:

```
@essays=Essay.find(Ranking.where(:user_id=>current_user.id).essay_id).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Comment: This is incorrect... for one thing `Essay.find` will only return one record. Doesn't make much sense to paginate on one record.

Comment: My bad. I thought the problem was only where to put the find to scope pagination. Also find on array of ids can return many recrods so then pagination makes sense.